# Why are two different keys overriding each other in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following three variables assigned:

```
const a = {key:true}
const b = {key:false}
const c = {[a]:'1',[b]:'2'}
```

When I then try to logged the following into the console:

```
console.log(c[a],c[b])
```

I got the following:

```
2 2
```

When I thought I should get:

```
1 2
```

Why am I wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Javascript 101... Lets you shoot yourself in the foot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look to `c`, where you see the result of `a.toString()`

```js
const a = { key: true }
const b = { key: false }
const c = { [a]: '1', [b]: '2' }

console.log(c);
console.log(c[a], c[b]);
```

For overcoming this problem, you could take a JSON string

```js
const a = { key: true }
const b = { key: false }
const c = { [JSON.stringify(a)]: '1', [JSON.stringify(b)]: '2' }

console.log(c);
console.log(c[JSON.stringify(a)], c[JSON.stringify(b)]);
```

Especial for objects as keys, you could use [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap):

```js
const a = { key: true }
const b = { key: false }
const c = new WeakMap([[a, '1'], [b, '2']]);

console.log(c.get(a), c.get(b));
```

Answer (score 9):

Objects can only have strings (or symbols) as their keys. If you try to use a non-string, it gets converted to a string. So when you set `c[a]` to be `1`, `a` is an object which means it needs to be converted to a string. So you end up setting `c["[object Object]"]` to be one. Then when you set `c[b]`, you do the same thing, again converting to `"[object Object]"` and thus overriding the value that's already there.

Try logging out `c` to see this:

```js
const a = {key:true}
const b = {key:false}
const c = {[a]:'1',[b]:'2'}
console.log(c);
```

It's unusual to need to use objects as keys, but if you need it, you can use [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of objects

```js
const a = {key:true}
const b = {key:false}
const c = new Map();
c.set(a, '1');
c.set(b, '2');
console.log(c.get(a));
console.log(c.get(b));
```

Comment: My design was counting on receiving a javascript json object with keys as object. Is there any way to save it or I have to redesign using maps?

Comment: In JSON that's impossible. JSON keys always are strings.

Comment: @StavAlfi:  [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Please clarify what you mean. Don't confuse JSON with JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 4):

> Why am I wrong and how can I fix it?

Object property names are converted to strings (if they are not strings or symbols). Object values by default serialize to `[object Object]`, so to JavaScript both values are identical:

```js
const a = {key:true}
const b = {key:false}

console.log('a', a.toString());
console.log('b', b.toString());
```

---

**1.** You can implement your own `toString` method to serialize the object to distinctive strings:

```js
function toString() {
  return this.key.toString();
}

const a = {key:true, toString}
const b = {key:false, toString}
const c = {[a]:'1',[b]:'2'}
console.log(c[a],c[b])
```

But that doesn't let you recover the original value that was used as key (you *could* use a JSON representation of the object as key, which you could convert back to an object, but that only works if the "key object" only contains values that can be expressed in JSON).

---

**2.** You can use a `Map` instead of an object, which allows for arbitrary values as keys:

```js
const a = {key:true}
const b = {key:false}
const c = new Map([[a, '1'], [b, '2']]);
console.log(c.get(a),c.get(b))
```

Note that `Map`s use object identity to look up values, so `c.get({key: false})` will not work.

---

Which way to go really depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Object keys are strings (or optionally Symbols, but that is neither here nor there).  If you console.log(c) you'll see that it is {[object Object]: "2"} because both [a] and [b] .toString() are "[object Object]"

As for "fixing" it... I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, so I can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: Object keys aren't always technically Symbols; they can be either strings or Symbols.